# Is the function $V (z)=\int_{ \mathbb {T} }\frac {e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}d\mu (e^{it})$ analytic on the unit disc $|z|<1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $\mathbb {T}$ be the unit circle in the complex plane and let $\mathbb{D}$ denote the open unit disc.
Let $\mu$ be a complex Borel measure on  $\mathbb {T}$ .
Is the function $V$ defined as $$V (z)=\int_{ \mathbb {T} }\frac {e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}d\mu (e^{it})\;\;  \;\;z\in \mathbb{D}  $$ analytic on $\mathbb{D}$? If yes, then How?

Comment: The denominator should read $e^{it} - z$, right?

Comment: $e^{it}$ is on the unit circle for all real values of $t$. Since $z$ takes values in the open unit disc, $z-e^{it}\neq 0$ for all real values of $t$.

Comment: Note simply that $|z|<1$ implies $$\frac {e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}=(1+e^{-it}z)\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-int}z^n=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-int}z^n$$ hence $$V(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty V_nz^n$$ with $$V_0=\int_\mathbb {T} d\mu (e^{it})$$ and, for every $n\geqslant1$, $$V_n=2\int_\mathbb {T} e^{-int}d\mu (e^{it})$$

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial \bar{z}}=0$

Comment: Can you tell why the integral $V(z)$ exists in the first place? Does $V(z)\in L1(T)$ for every $z$?

Comment: @user531706 what do you mean with $V(z)\in L^1(T)$? $V(z)$ is a number...

Comment: @Bob Sorry, I meant does the function $\frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z} \in L^1({\mathbb{T})}$ for every $z$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 
$$F(z,t)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} z^{|n|}e^{-i|n|t} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n}e^{-int}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^{n}e^{-int}  \\= \frac{1}{1-ze^{-it}}+ \frac{ze^{-it}}{1-ze^{-it}} =\frac {e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}$$
$z\mapsto F(z,t)$ is analytic on $\mathbb D$. Since $\mathbb T $ is compact, as  $\mu$ is a Borel measure  and hence finite on very compact sets in particular $\mu(\Bbb T)<\infty$. For fixed $z\in \Bbb D$ the map $t\mapsto F(z,t)$ is bounded on $\Bbb{T}$ and thus $V (z)\in L^1(\Bbb T)$

$$V (z)=\int_{ \mathbb {T} }\frac {e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}d\mu (e^{it}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} z^{|n|}\int_{ \mathbb {T} }e^{-i|n|t}d\mu (e^{it}) \\= \mu(\mathbb T) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(2\int_{ \mathbb {T} }e^{-int}d\mu (e^{it})\right)z^{n}  \;\;  \;\;z\in \mathbb{D}$$

that is

$$V (z)=\mu(\mathbb T) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  a_nz^{n}  \;\;  \;\;z\in \mathbb{D}$$
with $$a_n  =\left(2\int_{ \mathbb {T} }e^{-int}d\mu (e^{it})\right) \qquad\text{and}\qquad \mu(\mathbb T) =\int_{ \mathbb {T} }d\mu (e^{it}) $$

Comment: Can you tell why the integral $V(z)$ exists in the first place? Does $V(z)\in L^1(T)$ for every $z$?

Comment: @user531706 yes as  $\mu$ is a Borel measure and hence finite on very compact sets. for fixed $z$ $t\mapsto F(z,t)$ is bounded on $\Bbb{T}$

Answer (score 1):

$\bullet\;$ First show, for each fixed $t$, the function
$$
\frac {e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}
$$
is analytic on the open unit disk.

$\bullet\;$ Then find what is needed to verify this calculation: if $\gamma$ is a closed contour contained in the open unit disk, then
$$
\int_\gamma V (z)\;dz=
\int_{ \mathbb {T} }\int_\gamma \frac {e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}\;dz\;d\mu (e^{it}) = \int_{\mathbb T} 0\;d\mu(e^{it}) = 0.
$$

$\bullet\;$ Conclude that $V(z)$ is analytic.